# pyspark: How to simplify two `.over` operation?

Tags: python, pyspark

I have code that looks like

```
windowval = (Window.orderBy('colOrder').rangeBetween(Window.unboundedPreceding, 0))

dataframe.withColumn('a', F.sum(F.col('colA')).over(windowval)).\
          withColumn('b', F.sum(F.col('colB')).over(windowval)).\
          withColumn('aoverb', F.col('a')/F.col('b')).cache()

res1 = dataframe.agg(F.max('aoverb')).collect()[0][0]
res2 = dataframe.where(F.col('aoverb') == max_ratio).collect()[0]
```

and I use `res1` and `res2` in subsequent calculations.

However, I feel that I can combine the two `.over` operation into one to reduce calculations. Is Spark smart enough to compile that away?

Is there a more efficient way of writing this?

Answer (score 1):

I believe you could put all of that logic in the 'aoverb' column if you do not expect to use 'a' or 'b' individually.

```
windowval = (Window.orderBy('colOrder').rangeBetween(Window.unboundedPreceding, 0))

dataframe.withColumn(
    'aoverb', 
    F.sum(F.col('colA')).over(windowval)/F.sum(F.col('colB')).over(windowval)
).cache()
```